# Cocos2d-x UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found

Tags: c++, java-native-interface, cocos2d-x

**Update**

I solved my problem. The problem was in distinction between 3.0 and 2.0 versions cocos2d-x. For version 2.0 at .java file has to be the following code

```
static 
    {
        System.loadLibrary("cocos2dcpp");
    }
```

Maybe it will be useful for somebody.

I compiled app without errors, but after I run app on my device I have strange error.

```
05-22 08:43:38.477: E/AndroidRuntime(1493): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-22 08:43:38.477: E/AndroidRuntime(1493): java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Native method not found: org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxHelper.nativeSetApkPath:(Ljava/lang/String;)V
05-22 08:43:38.477: E/AndroidRuntime(1493):     at org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxHelper.nativeSetApkPath(Native Method)
05-22 08:43:38.477: E/AndroidRuntime(1493):     at org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxHelper.init(Cocos2dxHelper.java:71)
05-22 08:43:38.477: E/AndroidRuntime(1493):     at org.cocos2dx.lib.Cocos2dxActivity.onCreate(Cocos2dxActivity.java:68)
05-22 08:43:38.477: E/AndroidRuntime(1493):     at com.newhope.barman.barman.onCreate(barman.java:99)
05-22 08:43:38.477: E/AndroidRuntime(1493):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5133)
05-22 08:43:38.477: E/AndroidRuntime(1493):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
05-22 08:43:38.477: E/AndroidRuntime(1493):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2175)
05-22 08:43:38.477: E/AndroidRuntime(1493):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2261)
05-22 08:43:38.477: E/AndroidRuntime(1493):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
05-22 08:43:38.477: E/AndroidRuntime(1493):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1256)
05-22 08:43:38.477: E/AndroidRuntime(1493):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-22 08:43:38.477: E/AndroidRuntime(1493):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-22 08:43:38.477: E/AndroidRuntime(1493):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5103)
05-22 08:43:38.477: E/AndroidRuntime(1493):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-22 08:43:38.477: E/AndroidRuntime(1493):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
05-22 08:43:38.477: E/AndroidRuntime(1493):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
05-22 08:43:38.477: E/AndroidRuntime(1493):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
05-22 08:43:38.477: E/AndroidRuntime(1493):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Tell me please, what I do wrong? Thanks for your help!

Comment: what instructions are you trying to follow?

Comment: I try connect Admob follow instructions, which describe here http://www.cocos2d-x.org/forums/6/topics/50259?page=1

Comment: It looks like it is trying to find `Cocos2dxHelper.nativeSetApkPath` Did you make it all the way through the tutorial?

Comment: Yes, I did it step by step. Cocos2dxHelper.nativeSetApkPath is included in org.cocos2dx.lib